# How to pass two parameters in AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-asynctask, android-livedata

I am using MVVM structure and my query in Dao looks like:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Sorted WHERE date LIKE :date AND categoryChart = :category")
LiveData<List<Sorted>> getSortedDiagramData(String date, String category);
```

In Repository I need to execute this method in AsyncTask, but I don't understand how to do it.

What I've tried:

```
 public LiveData<List<Sorted>> getSortedDiagramData(String date, String category){
    String[] array = new String[2];
    array[0] = date;
    array[1] = category;
    return new GetSortedDiagramDataAsyncTask(sortedDao).execute(array);
}
```

And then:

```
 private static class GetSortedDiagramDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, LiveData<List<Sorted>>> {
    private SortedDao sortedDao;
    private GetSortedDiagramDataAsyncTask(SortedDao sortedDao){
        this.sortedDao = sortedDao;
    }
    @Override
    protected LiveData<List<Sorted>> doInBackground(String[] ... strings) {
        String date1 = String.valueOf(strings[0]);
        String category1 = String.valueOf(strings[1]);
        LiveData<List<Sorted>> list = sortedDao.getSortedDiagramData(date1, category1);
        return list;
    }
}
```

But when I pass "array" to execute() there is an error "Incompatible types".

Could you please suggest how I can solve this problem? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Pass the parameters in the constructor

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: You already have an example. It is in your question. `GetSortedDiagramDataAsyncTask` has a constructor: `GetSortedDiagramDataAsyncTask(SortedDao sortedDao)`. You can add other parameters to that and store them in fields the way that you are storing `sortedDao`. Note, though, that `AsyncTask` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it in the constructor:

```
private String date, category;
private SortedDao sortedDao;
public GetSortedDiagramDataAsyncTask(SortedDao sortedDao, String date, String category) {
    this.date = date;
    this.category = category;
    this.sortedDao = sortedDao;
}

@Override
protected LiveData<List<Sorted>> doInBackground(String[]... strings) {
    LiveData<List<Sorted>> list = sortedDao.getSortedDiagramData(date, category);
    return list;
}
```

Call it as:

```
new GetSortedDiagramDataAsyncTask(sortedDao, "date", "category").execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use this:

```
GetSortedDiagramDataAsyncTask(sortedDao).execute(date,category);
```